# I want to append values in this HTML request

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have this code below to convert a HTML file that is being read in .xls to google sheets. I found this solution code below to find the HTML tables in my google sheets BUT I need it to append the tables.

Example of my google sheets:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t4FFBzRo2Qi7tfTfeZpnMdvp7U71kC7Nrt-8hT0OVMc/edit?usp=sharing --- This is just a snippet as the file is 5000 rows of this but I can add more as requested.

I attempted to change the "rowIndex" to be "destinationSheet.getLastRow() so that it grows as multiple tables are pasted BUT it seems to not update in the while loop. It will go to row 1 and then try to paste multiple HTML tables on top of each other.

My goal is to have HTML Table 1 be pasted onto my google sheets. Let's say it is 20 rows, find HTML Table 2 and go to row 21 and paste the second table and so on.

```
function myFunction() {
  var fileId = '###';  // Please set the file ID of HTML file.
  var spreadsheetId = '###';  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID for putting the values.
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name for putting the values.


  // Retrieve tables from HTML data.
  var html = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var values = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>/gi);

  // Put the HTML tables to the Spreadsheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var rowIndex = 0;
  values.forEach(function(e) {
    
    var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: e, coordinate: {sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: rowIndex}}}]};
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
    
    
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some of the contents of your html?

Comment: I added more of the contents but please let me know if it wasn't enough. Essentially, they are 5x5 tables of sales. Columns are types of sales made. Rows describe them further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

Your `rowIndex` in the provided code doesn't increment.

#### Proposed Solution:

Easiest and fastest way to adjust your existing code is to count the rows per table via matching `<tr>` tags and get the length of it.

#### Code:

```
values.forEach(function(e) {
  var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: e, coordinate: {sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: rowIndex}}}]};
  // count rows per table, and increment your rowIndex with that value
  rowIndex += e.match(/<tr>/gi).length;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
});
```

#### HTML File:

[image: html file]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### EDIT:

- Update the match call to `rowIndex += e.match(/<tr[\w\s\S]+?<\/tr>/gi).length;`

#### Test data:

[image: output2]

Comment: This solution works! It definitely appends the various tables together. However, for some reason, I am not getting the same structure as yours. My tables on seem to get the header row + maybe one other row. I've updated my google sheets to be my entire sheet I'm working with. Could you see if your code will process it into tables without issue?

Comment: I have modified my answer, see section **EDIT:**. It actually worked without any issues. I just modified the match regex. can you check if that's the same case as yours?

Comment: chef's kiss. That works perfectly and gets everything I need. Thank you sooo much!! I was stuck on this for a few days since I don't know html well.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
  const fileId = gobj.globals.htmlfileid;
  const html = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const tables = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>/gi);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.ssid);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  let resource = { requests: [] };
  let n=0;
  tables.forEach(t => {
    values = Utilities.parseCsv(t.replace(/<table>/gi,'').replace(/<\/table>/gi,'').replace(/<tr>/gi,'').replace(/<th>/gi,'').replace(/<th>/gi,'').replace(/<td>/gi,'').replace(/<\/td><\/tr>/gi,'\r\n').replace(/<\/th><\/tr>/gi,'\r\n').replace(/<\/td>/gi,'~').replace(/<\/th>/gi,'~'),'~');
    Logger.log(values);
    values.forEach((r, i) => {
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        resource.requests.push({ pasteData: { html: true, data: c, coordinate: { "sheetId": sheetId, "rowIndex": n, "columnIndex": j } } }); 
      });
      n++;
    });
  });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, gobj.globals.ssid);
}
```

My data was generated from this:

```
function createHTMLTable() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let html = '<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>';
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    html += '<tr>';
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        html += Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>', c)
      } else {
        html += Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>', c)
      }
    });
    html += '</tr>'
  });
  html += '</table>';
  Logger.log(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Html Table');
  return html;
}
```

It came from Sheet1:

Which looks like this:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3 | 1,4 | 1,5 | 1,6 | 1,7 | 1,8 | 1,9 | 1,10 |
| 2,1 | 2,2 | 2,3 | 2,4 | 2,5 | 2,6 | 2,7 | 2,8 | 2,9 | 2,10 |
| 3,1 | 3,2 | 3,3 | 3,4 | 3,5 | 3,6 | 3,7 | 3,8 | 3,9 | 3,10 |
| 4,1 | 4,2 | 4,3 | 4,4 | 4,5 | 4,6 | 4,7 | 4,8 | 4,9 | 4,10 |
| 5,1 | 5,2 | 5,3 | 5,4 | 5,5 | 5,6 | 5,7 | 5,8 | 5,9 | 5,10 |
| 6,1 | 6,2 | 6,3 | 6,4 | 6,5 | 6,6 | 6,7 | 6,8 | 6,9 | 6,10 |
| 7,1 | 7,2 | 7,3 | 7,4 | 7,5 | 7,6 | 7,7 | 7,8 | 7,9 | 7,10 |
| 8,1 | 8,2 | 8,3 | 8,4 | 8,5 | 8,6 | 8,7 | 8,8 | 8,9 | 8,10 |
| 9,1 | 9,2 | 9,3 | 9,4 | 9,5 | 9,6 | 9,7 | 9,8 | 9,9 | 9,10 |
| 10,1 | 10,2 | 10,3 | 10,4 | 10,5 | 10,6 | 10,7 | 10,8 | 10,9 | 10,10 |

And the output looks exactly the same.

My html file contents:

```
<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>COL1</th><th>COL2</th><th>COL3</th><th>COL4</th><th>COL5</th><th>COL6</th><th>COL7</th><th>COL8</th><th>COL9</th><th>COL10</th></tr><tr><td>1,1</td><td>1,2</td><td>1,3</td><td>1,4</td><td>1,5</td><td>1,6</td><td>1,7</td><td>1,8</td><td>1,9</td><td>1,10</td></tr><tr><td>2,1</td><td>2,2</td><td>2,3</td><td>2,4</td><td>2,5</td><td>2,6</td><td>2,7</td><td>2,8</td><td>2,9</td><td>2,10</td></tr><tr><td>3,1</td><td>3,2</td><td>3,3</td><td>3,4</td><td>3,5</td><td>3,6</td><td>3,7</td><td>3,8</td><td>3,9</td><td>3,10</td></tr><tr><td>4,1</td><td>4,2</td><td>4,3</td><td>4,4</td><td>4,5</td><td>4,6</td><td>4,7</td><td>4,8</td><td>4,9</td><td>4,10</td></tr><tr><td>5,1</td><td>5,2</td><td>5,3</td><td>5,4</td><td>5,5</td><td>5,6</td><td>5,7</td><td>5,8</td><td>5,9</td><td>5,10</td></tr><tr><td>6,1</td><td>6,2</td><td>6,3</td><td>6,4</td><td>6,5</td><td>6,6</td><td>6,7</td><td>6,8</td><td>6,9</td><td>6,10</td></tr><tr><td>7,1</td><td>7,2</td><td>7,3</td><td>7,4</td><td>7,5</td><td>7,6</td><td>7,7</td><td>7,8</td><td>7,9</td><td>7,10</td></tr><tr><td>8,1</td><td>8,2</td><td>8,3</td><td>8,4</td><td>8,5</td><td>8,6</td><td>8,7</td><td>8,8</td><td>8,9</td><td>8,10</td></tr><tr><td>9,1</td><td>9,2</td><td>9,3</td><td>9,4</td><td>9,5</td><td>9,6</td><td>9,7</td><td>9,8</td><td>9,9</td><td>9,10</td></tr><tr><td>10,1</td><td>10,2</td><td>10,3</td><td>10,4</td><td>10,5</td><td>10,6</td><td>10,7</td><td>10,8</td><td>10,9</td><td>10,10</td></tr></table><style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>COL1</th><th>COL2</th><th>COL3</th><th>COL4</th><th>COL5</th><th>COL6</th><th>COL7</th><th>COL8</th><th>COL9</th><th>COL10</th></tr><tr><td>1,1</td><td>1,2</td><td>1,3</td><td>1,4</td><td>1,5</td><td>1,6</td><td>1,7</td><td>1,8</td><td>1,9</td><td>1,10</td></tr><tr><td>2,1</td><td>2,2</td><td>2,3</td><td>2,4</td><td>2,5</td><td>2,6</td><td>2,7</td><td>2,8</td><td>2,9</td><td>2,10</td></tr><tr><td>3,1</td><td>3,2</td><td>3,3</td><td>3,4</td><td>3,5</td><td>3,6</td><td>3,7</td><td>3,8</td><td>3,9</td><td>3,10</td></tr><tr><td>4,1</td><td>4,2</td><td>4,3</td><td>4,4</td><td>4,5</td><td>4,6</td><td>4,7</td><td>4,8</td><td>4,9</td><td>4,10</td></tr><tr><td>5,1</td><td>5,2</td><td>5,3</td><td>5,4</td><td>5,5</td><td>5,6</td><td>5,7</td><td>5,8</td><td>5,9</td><td>5,10</td></tr><tr><td>6,1</td><td>6,2</td><td>6,3</td><td>6,4</td><td>6,5</td><td>6,6</td><td>6,7</td><td>6,8</td><td>6,9</td><td>6,10</td></tr><tr><td>7,1</td><td>7,2</td><td>7,3</td><td>7,4</td><td>7,5</td><td>7,6</td><td>7,7</td><td>7,8</td><td>7,9</td><td>7,10</td></tr><tr><td>8,1</td><td>8,2</td><td>8,3</td><td>8,4</td><td>8,5</td><td>8,6</td><td>8,7</td><td>8,8</td><td>8,9</td><td>8,10</td></tr><tr><td>9,1</td><td>9,2</td><td>9,3</td><td>9,4</td><td>9,5</td><td>9,6</td><td>9,7</td><td>9,8</td><td>9,9</td><td>9,10</td></tr><tr><td>10,1</td><td>10,2</td><td>10,3</td><td>10,4</td><td>10,5</td><td>10,6</td><td>10,7</td><td>10,8</td><td>10,9</td><td>10,10</td></tr></table>
```